# Core Image gray scale filter and sepia filter iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm trying to implement a gray scale filter and sepia filter  on an image loaded into the UIImageView from the photo library.  i found in tutorials (I'm new to core Image) but then I want to put the sepia image back into the same same UIImageView when ever I try to put the new image into the view it just disappears I have tested to see if the image view contains an image and it does but it is not visible. any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Please do some googling before posting such a question here. There are n number of tools/ tutorials available for such an effect. You can study that and implement them in your app as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check these links. Hope you will get the solution..

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

http://www.willpowell.co.uk/blog/2014/09/14/15-image-filtering-processing-ocr-utilities-helper-libraries-frameworks-ios-iphone-ipad-development/

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link. Hope you will get the proper solution..

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters